# gRPC response headers based on the incoming value

Tags: java, header, grpc, interceptor, grpc-java

I need to send the response headers for the gRPC request based on the incoming value. The way of doing this is by using ServerInterceptor. But here I'm a bit stuck. I'm able to intercept the incoming value using `ForwardingServerCallListener.SimpleForwardingServerCallListener#onMessage`, but I don't see the way to put this value into the context and read it in the `ForwardingServerCall.SimpleForwardingServerCall#sendHeaders`.

Here is my code:

```
public class FooInterceptor implements ServerInterceptor {

    @Override
    public <ReqT, RespT> ServerCall.Listener<ReqT> interceptCall(ServerCall<ReqT, RespT> call, Metadata headers, ServerCallHandler<ReqT, RespT> next) {
        var serverCall = new ForwardingServerCall.SimpleForwardingServerCall<>(call) {
            @Override
            public void sendHeaders(Metadata headers) {
                //Here I should get the value from the context and add it to the headers
                //var foo = CONTEXT_KEY.get("foo");
                //headers.put(METADATA_KEY, foo);
                super.sendHeaders(headers);
            }
        }
        ServerCall.Listener<ReqT> listenerWithContext = Contexts
                .interceptCall(Context.current(), serverCall, headers, next);
        return new ForwardingServerCallListener.SimpleForwardingServerCallListener<>(listenerWithContext) {
            @Override
            public void onMessage(ReqT message) {
                if (message instanceof FooRequest) {
                    var foo = ((FooRequest) message).getFoo();
                    //How to add it to context?
                }
                super.onMessage(message);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

So the problem is in the method `ForwardingServerCallListener.SimpleForwardingServerCallListener#onMessage` I'm able to get the value from the message, but I'm not able to rewrite the context there with the new value.
Any ideas/suggestions would be appreciated very much!

Answer (score 2):

I found a workaround, it's not the most elegant solution, but it seems to work. Will post it here since there are no other answers yet.

I've managed to pass the value using the requests headers.
So, in `ForwardingServerCallListener.SimpleForwardingServerCallListener#onMessage` I'm setting the value to the request headers and inside the `ForwardingServerCall.SimpleForwardingServerCall#sendHeaders` I write it the value from the request headers and write it to the response headers.

Here is the code:

```
public class FooInterceptor implements ServerInterceptor {

    @Override
    public <ReqT, RespT> ServerCall.Listener<ReqT> interceptCall(ServerCall<ReqT, RespT> call, Metadata headers, ServerCallHandler<ReqT, RespT> next) {
        var serverCall = new ForwardingServerCall.SimpleForwardingServerCall<>(call) {
            @Override
            public void sendHeaders(Metadata responseHeaders) {
                var foo = headers.get(Metadata.Key.of("x-value"), Metadata.ASCII_STRING_MARSHALLER));
                responseHeaders.put(Metadata.Key.of("x-value"), Metadata.ASCII_STRING_MARSHALLER), foo);
                super.sendHeaders(responseHeaders);
            }
        }
        ServerCall.Listener<ReqT> listenerWithContext = Contexts
                .interceptCall(Context.current(), serverCall, headers, next);
        return new ForwardingServerCallListener.SimpleForwardingServerCallListener<>(listenerWithContext) {
            @Override
            public void onMessage(ReqT message) {
                if (message instanceof FooRequest) {
                    var foo = ((FooRequest) message).getFoo();
                    headers.put(Metadata.Key.of("x-value"), Metadata.ASCII_STRING_MARSHALLER), foo);
                }
                super.onMessage(message);
            }
        };
    }
}
```